# Как double разделить на 2 int ?java

Tags: java

Как выполнить задание? Нужно double(8 байт) разделить на int(по 4 байта)

первые 4 байта - первое число

вторые 4 байта - второе число

как это сделать объясните пожалуйста

Comment: а что вы вкладываете в слово `разделить`? Просто 4 байта из 8 получить как-то? А зачем такое в Java? В С я бы ещё понял. Какая ваша _основная_ задача

Comment: Извините, но разве в самом задании не понятно написано?

Comment: double 8 байтов, нужно взять первые 4 байта - это первое число инт, остальные 4 байта другое

Answer (score 5):

Не знаю зачем вам это (поэтому не знаю с какой стороны вам резать), но как вариант можно так:

```
byte[] b = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putDouble(2.13547).array();
int x1 = b[0] + 256*b[1] + 65536*b[2] + 1677721*b[3];
int x2 = b[4] + 256*b[5] + 65536*b[6] + 1677721*b[7];
```

[Документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/class-use/ByteBuffer.html)

Comment: Есть ли вариант чтобы это сделать с помощью побитового сдвига?

Comment: @j6wj1997 можно. А какая разница? Только двигайте аккуратно.

Comment: Спасибо) все понятно

Answer (score 5):

Методы [`Double.doubleToLongBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits-double-) и [`Double.doubleToRawLongBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits-double-) возвращают `long` с битами `double` в формате IEEE 754.

```
double t = 123.456;

long t_bits = Double.doubleToLongBits( t );

int a = (int)( (t_bits >> 32) );
int b = (int)( t_bits );

System.out.printf( "t: %f, a: %d, b: %d%n", t, a, b );
// t: 123,456000, a: 1079958831, b: 446676599
```

Обратно:

```
double t_2 = Double.longBitsToDouble( ((long)a << 32) + b );

System.out.printf( "t_2: %f%n", t_2 );
// t_2: 123,456000
```